# What is the difference between the `!has` and `!has_cs` string operators in KQL?

Tags: azure, kql

What is the difference between the `!has` and `!has_cs` string operators in KQL?

There is [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/has-operator). It says that both the `"North America" !has "amer"` and the `"North America" !has_cs "amer"` will return true.

If the `!has` would not have been case sensitive I would expect the `"North America" !has "amer"` to return `false`, since `America` contains the `amer` if we ignore the casing. But it returns `true`. Hence, I conclude that the `!has` is case sensitive and behaves exactly the same as the `!has_cs`. Is it really the case or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*has_cs* is case sensitive.
*has* is case-insensitive.

Both of your conditions return true since *has* looks for a **whole** term.
A term is a sequence of **alpha-numeric** ASCII characters (see [What is a term?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/datatypes-string-operators#what-is-a-term))

In your example `amer` is just a (case-insensitive) piece (the prefix) of the whole term, which is `America`, therefore *has* returns false.